# Cosmos DB SQL equivalent of Object.keys

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Because of array ordering issues with change detection AND the fact that the schema in the array is inconsistent, i'd prefer to structure arrays of object more as dictionaries, or plain JSON objects, with keys of each object id.

For example, instead of:

```
{id: 'abc', items: [{id: 'xyz', text:'foo'},{id: 'wxy', name:'bar'}]}
```

I'd prefer:

```
{id: 'abc', items: {'xyz': {text:'foo'},'wxy', {name:'bar'}}}
```

It's there anyway in Cosmos SQL API to query an object and list it's keys and/or the values since the keys are inconsistent between objects?

I'm looking for something equivalent to Object.keys() or Object.values() in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your Q off hand but one thing with your proposed new schema is this will make Synapse / Analytical Storage feature unusable for you. You will get an explosion of property paths and quickly exceed the 1,000 maximum unique property paths per collection

Comment: Thanks... i was unaware of that limitation and can't seem to find that documented.  I only find limitation for unique key constraints.

Comment: It is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction#schema-constraints . If you aren't planning on using this feature it doesn't make any difference to you though.

Comment: To order something in Cosmos DB, use a composite index on the container and an Order By in your queries. More info here, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview#composite-indexes